# NATS error: 'Unresponsive client detected, connection dropped'

Tags: cloud-foundry

After deploying approximately 70/100 apps at the same time, everything seemed to stop and I stopped the last 30 deployments. However, some time after, all the apps stopped working and I found the following log entry in my dea.log:

```
[2012-11-06 14:35:14.295386] dea - pid=1390 tid=7e88 fid=592d  ERROR -- EXITING! NATS error: 'Unresponsive client detected, connection dropped'
[2012-11-06 14:35:14.295478] dea exception pid=1390 tid=7e88 fid=592d  ERROR -- NATS::ServerError<<'Unresponsive client detected, connection dropped':>>
```

All other components of CF seems to work perfectly, but the two DEA servers now won't start any applications. Any idea what could be wrong? Let me know if you need more information, I would love to provide more - but I'm not sure what is relevant.

**Edit:**

I don't experience this issue, when `enforce_ulimit: false` in dea.yml

**Edit2:**

I get this new error, after setting `enforce_ulimit: true` in dea.yml

```
[2012-11-06 16:32:32.905127] dea - pid=2143 tid=967a fid=d902  ERROR -- EXITING! NATS error: Unknown protocol: {"droplet":490,"limits":{"mem":64,"disk":2048,"fds":256},"name":"gurodari","runtime_info":{"version":"2.6.5","description":"Python 2.6.5","executable":"python","version_output":"2.[5-7]","version_flag":"--version","environment":{"PATH":"/usr/bin:$PATH"},"nameINFO {"server_id":"a746ae3260317c8fa8c0a0dd57","host":"<ip removed>","port":4222,"version":"0.4.26","auth_required":true,"ssl_required":false,"max_payload":1048576}
[2012-11-06 16:32:32.905936] dea exception pid=2143 tid=967a fid=d902  ERROR -- NATS::ServerError<<Unknown protocol: {"droplet":490,"limits":{"mem":64,"disk":2048,"fds":256},"name":"gurodari","runtime_info":{"version":"2.6.5","description":"Python 2.6.5","executable":"python","version_output":"2.[5-7]","version_flag":"--version","environment":{"PATH":"/usr/bin:$PATH"},"nameINFO {"server_id":"a746ae3260317c8fa8c0a0dd57","host":"<ip removed>","port":4222,"version":"0.4.26","auth_required":true,"ssl_required":false,"max_payload":1048576}:>>
```

Comment: Did you try Cloudfoundry support?  In any case, this is an admin problem which would be better raised on ServerFault, I think.

Comment: It's not the cloudfoundry public cloud. It is an installation on our own servers. Furthermore, cloudfoundry encourages everyone to open their issues on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's very nice of them, but they don't get to dictate policy about which questions are appropriate on which sites.  Your question really feels more like an admin than a development issue.  The fact that these are your servers isn't really relevant.  I'll raise it on Meta, see what they think.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the discussion around the Cloud Foundry OSS project (vcap) is happening on the google group: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

I'd suggest posting over there.